# onkeydown keydown:37 not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keydown

In my code i have 4 boxes .I've divided the boxes in two groups.
I'm using Jquery keydown fucntion,
Everything is working fine but when i press 37 second group is doing correct work but that time first group don't giving any result but when i remove the Jquery codes of second group the first group working.

```
onkeydown = function(e) {

e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
  $('.slide1').removeClass('activeslide').next().addClass('activeslide');

  };
};
    onkeydown = function(e) {

e = e || window.event;
if (e.keyCode == 37) {
  $('.notslide1').removeClass('notactiveslide').next().addClass('notactiveslide');

  };
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/27kd4sre/1/)

Comment: You are setting `onkeydown` twice. So you will only get last value

Comment: Actually this is false code ,my project code is too much big and if i want to show the code i have to show full 1000line code so i've made this code,
In my original code in place of slide1/notslide1 i've got if else query as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onkeydown = function(e) {

    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $('.slide1').removeClass('activeslide').next().addClass('activeslide');
        $('.notslide1').removeClass('notactiveslide').next().addClass('notactiveslide');
    }

}
```

Comment: this is correct but in my original code i have to run lots of if else so is it possible to run your format in my code?

Comment: The number of if-else really doesn't matter, make sure you have only one event listener initialized where you can check all pressed keys events.